# Not able to build Ionic 2 project

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I migrated the ionic 2 project to the latest version (i.e, 3.0.0). Everything was perfect until, i generated a new page (`DiscountOption`) in the project today. It generated 4 files instead of 3 (*.module.ts is the new one).

Here is my code:

discount-option.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DiscountOption } from './discount-option';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DiscountOption,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(DiscountOption),
  ],
  exports: [
    DiscountOption
  ]
})
export class DiscountOptionModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
...
import { DiscountOption } from '../pages/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    DiscountOption
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
    DiscountOption
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

(... code shortened for brevity)

When i tried to build the app using `ionic build android --prod`

I get this error,

```
[11:35:52]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[11:35:52]  Error: Type DiscountOption in E:/TFS
            SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/pages/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option.ts is part of the
            declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in E:/TFS SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/app/app.module.ts and
            DiscountOptionModule in E:/TFS
            SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/pages/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option.module.ts! Please consider
            moving DiscountOption in E:/TFS
            SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/pages/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option.ts to a higher module that
            imports AppModule in E:/TFS SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/app/app.module.ts and DiscountOptionModule in E:/TFS
            SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/pages/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option.module.ts. You can also
            create a new NgModule that exports and includes DiscountOption in E:/TFS
            SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/pages/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option.ts then import that NgModule
            in AppModule in E:/TFS SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/app/app.module.ts and DiscountOptionModule in E:/TFS
            SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/pages/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option.module.ts.
Error: Type DiscountOption in E:/TFS SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/pages/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option.ts is part of
 the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in E:/TFS SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/app/app.module.ts and DiscountOptionModule in E:/T
FS SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/pages/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option.module.ts! Please consider moving DiscountOptio
n in E:/TFS SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/pages/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option.ts to a higher module that imports App
Module in E:/TFS SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/app/app.module.ts and DiscountOptionModule in E:/TFS SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/page
s/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes DiscountOp
tion in E:/TFS SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/pages/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option.ts then import that NgModule in App
Module in E:/TFS SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/app/app.module.ts and DiscountOptionModule in E:/TFS SOURCE/HMS/HMS.App/eKot/src/page
s/orders/biller/discount-option/discount-option.module.ts.
at Error (native)
    at syntaxError (E:\TFS SOURCE\HMS\HMS.App\eKot\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1513:34)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (E:\TFS SOURCE\HMS\HMS.App\eKot\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.um
d.js:14118:31)
    at E:\TFS SOURCE\HMS\HMS.App\eKot\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14007:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (E:\TFS SOURCE\HMS\HMS.App\eKot\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler
.umd.js:13998:54)
    at addNgModule (E:\TFS SOURCE\HMS\HMS.App\eKot\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22526:58)
    at E:\TFS SOURCE\HMS\HMS.App\eKot\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22537:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _createNgModules (E:\TFS SOURCE\HMS\HMS.App\eKot\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22536:26)
```

I know this error is due to declaring the module twice in app.module and the newly generated module file. I don't know how to make it work. Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Here is my Ionic Info

E:\TFS SOURCE\HMS\HMS.App\eKot>ionic info

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [google docs regarding ionic v3](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGokwMXPQItZmTHZQbTO4qwj_SQymFhRS_nJmiH0K3w/edit).

Remove any reference to the `DiscountOption` page from **app.module.ts**.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Your page will be referenced and declared in **page.module.ts**

If you are importing the page anywhere else remove it.. use a string equivalent of the class name.Also add `@IonicPage()` in `DiscountOption`

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'discount-option.html'
})
export class DiscountOption {}
```

Reference:[IonicPage](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I removed the references, and the project is built. but when i run it on the device, the page is not showing. When i served it in browser, the console shows an error `No component factory found for DiscountOption. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`. i need to reference it in the app.module.ts, which directly contradicts with the answer!

Comment: have you imported the page in app.component.ts?

Comment: Just to be sure, is it app.component.ts or app.module.ts?

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/ check my update in answer..

Comment: I have removed all the reference of `DiscountOption` from app.module.ts and also in a page `BillerPage` and used the equivalent string `DiscountOption` to navigate to that page. When i serve it, it says Typescript error: cannot find name 'DiscountOption'. Did exactly as in the docs.

Comment: sry.. add `@IonicPage()` above `@component` in DiscountOption

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140147/discussion-between-ranjith-varadan-and-suraj).

Comment: Thanks for the doc reference @suraj

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using Ionic 3 Lazy Loading feature, Just remove your page's `yourPage.module.ts`.It is an **optional** one.

Comment: just curious what do you think of the lazy loading feature?

Comment: Please see this doc:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGokwMXPQItZmTHZQbTO4qwj_SQymFhRS_nJmiH0K3w/edit#heading=h.yw70uq35xyz8 @suraj

Comment: I have read it.. I referenced it in my answer :) .. not sure about converting every page/component into its own module though..

Comment: You can utilize that feature only when you have done that way.Otherwise its just like an old pattern.i.e. load everything upfront.But this is an optional feature.If you want, you can use old pattern with the Ionic 3 also.@suraj

Comment: In what situation, i can use this lazy loading feature? My app has like 5 pages. is it useful to use this feature in this app?

Comment: Hence your app is very small one, you can use default pattern (Ionic 2).I don't see any issue about it.But if you have a huge scope in the feature with this app, then it is better to go with the latest lazy loading pattern.